# OCaml: trying to count frequency of char in a string

Tags: count, ocaml, frequency

```
let countA =0 in
let countC =0 in
let countG =0 in
let countT =0 in
let countChar x =
  match x with 
  'A' -> countA = countA + 1
  |'C'-> countC = countC + 1
  |'G' -> countG = countG + 1
  |'T'-> countT = countT + 1
;;
```

I am getting a syntax error but I don't understand why, i'm still pretty new to Ocaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax error is caused by the fact that your last `let` doesn't have an `in` after it. This, in turn, is caused by the fact that your `countChar` function isn't defined at the outermost level (of a module). If you want to define a series of top-level names, you should define them all without `in`:

```
let countA = 0
let countC = 0
let countChar x = ...
```

So, that's your syntax problem. However, there are many other problems with this code.

The most obvious two are (A) you're expecting to be able to change the values of `countA` and so on. But they are immutable values, you can't change them. (B) You are using `=` as if it's an assignment operator. But in OCaml this is a comparison operator. Your code is just *comparing* `countA` against `countA + 1`. So of course the result is `false`.

It is definitely worth learning how to compute with immutable values, so I would try to fix this code by learning how to carry the cumulative counts as function parameters and return them at the end. But if you insist on coding imperatively, you will have to use references for your counts.

I also don't see any code that works on a string. Your `countChar` function (as the name implies) works on just one character.

**Update**

Here is a function that counts how many even and odd ints appear in an array. It works without mutating anything:

```
let eoa array =
    let rec inner n (evenct, oddct) =
        if n >= Array.length array then
            (evenct, oddct)
        else
            let newcounts =
                if array.(n) mod 2 = 0 then (evenct + 1, oddct)
                else (evenct, oddct + 1)
            in
            inner (n + 1) newcounts
     in
     inner 0 (0, 0)
```

Here's how it looks when you run it:

```
# eoa [| 3; 1; 4; 1; 5; 9; 2 |];;
- : int * int = (2, 5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I might have to try using the reference approach to these since I don't believe ocaml has mutable objects.

Comment: Hmm. Well OCaml does have mutable objects and references are mutable objects. It's also worth noting that OCaml arrays are mutable. They might be worth looking at.

Comment: I am currently working on a project where this code came from and was wondering if you could check it out and give me some pointers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034210/ocaml-how-to-count-substring-in-a-string?noredirect=1#comment67350159_40034210 I've asked the question at this link