# OCaml: how to count substring in a string

Tags: string, iteration, substring, ocaml, project

I am fairly new to OCaml but I have this project that i'm working on, I don't really understand the concept of immutable objects and was wondering if i could get some help, I am doing this through a text editor and have tried String.iter and explode but still can't manage to figure it out.

```
Description:
You are given a DNA sequence:
a string that contains only characters 'A', 'C', 'G', and 'T'.
Your task is to calculate the number of substrings of sequence,
in which each of the symbols appears the same number of times.

Example 1:
For sequence = "ACGTACGT", the output should be 6
All substrings of length 4 contain each symbol exactly once (+5),
and the whole sequence contains each symbol twice (+1).

Example 2:
For sequence = "AAACCGGTTT", the output should be 1
Only substring "AACCGGTT" satisfies the criterion above: it contains each symbol twice.


Input: String, a sequence that consists only of symbols 'A', 'C', 'G', and 'T'.
Length constraint: 0 < sequence.length < 100000.
```

> Output: Integer, the number of substrings where each symbol appears equally many times.

**EDIT** This is what I currently have:

```
let countA = ref 0 
let countC = ref 0 
let countG = ref 0  
let countT = ref 0  
let subStricount = ref 0

let countChar x = 
    match x with
    'A'-> countA +1
    |'C'-> countC +1
    |'T'-> countT +1
    |'G'-> countG +1
;;



let tempH = 0 in 
let tempT = 3 in
let demoStri = "ACGTACGT" in 
let striL = String.length demoStri in 
for i = 0 to striL -1 do 
    for j = tempH to tempT do
        countChar demoStri.[tempH];
    done
done
```

Comment: I do not understand "through a text editor".  Anyway, show what you have done so far.

Comment: Same question in F#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010725/how-do-i-find-a-substring-within-a-string-in-f  The question is also found in https://codefights.com/challenge/fYqpnHtuii9QwwTSt

Comment: It might help: [suffix trees](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/suffixtrees.pdf)

Comment: thank you everyone, I'll look into them.

Comment: this is my current progress of doing it, I was wondering if I could get some feedback, I apologize for all the erros, I am only three weeks into this language.

Comment: This looks like a pretty hairy problem. It might be better to warm up on some easier problems if you're just learning OCaml :-) At any rate you might start by planning out your algorithm independently of the language you're going to use. There are n * (n + 1) / 2 nonempty substrings of a string of length n, and you need to look at all of them (or all of them that are a multiple of 4 in length). That's a lot of looking when n is 100000.

Comment: This is actually a project i'm working on for school so I kind of have to, I'm trying to do what camispotter has linked me with the f# version, but since there are mutable objects its a completely different story.